# Unable to fetch records using unidirectional @OneToMany relationaship JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm unable to fetch records using a unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship in JPA.  Any idea if anything is missing?
Records are getting persisted though; only retrieving records is having problems.

```java
class Employee{

    int empId;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "deptId",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    List<Department> departments=new ArrayList<>();

    //getters and setters

}

class Department{

    String code;
    ....
    int deptId;

    //getters and setters

}

empRepository.findById(empId).getDepartments(); // is not returning rows even if records are available.
```

Comment: You'll need to provide way more details. How do you verify "records" are available. How do you create these rows, what transactions are involved? What SQL is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`@JoinColumn(name = "deptId")`** with **`@OneToMany`** here is reference the best way to implement the one to Many unidirectional  or Bi-directional relation in JPA

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

https://medium.com/@rajibrath20/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate-dbbf6dba00d3

Comment: Thanks a lot Shaam for your guidance it was really helpful :)